# Uncheck all Checkbox in Gridview when selecting one in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I have a DataGridView bounded to an Oracle Database with a checkbox column. The idea is than when I select one checkbox, the rest of them uncheck automatically or find a way to validate that there's only one selected when pressing the "Confirm" button. I can get the index and the values of the checkbox row, but I can't set values to the checkboxes.

This is the code i'm using for *get*

```
Private Function GetSelectedRow() As Integer()
    Dim Array As Integer() = {0, 0}
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim id_propuesta As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView3.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(GridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
        If cb IsNot Nothing Then
            If cb.Checked Then
                Dim hf As HiddenField = DirectCast(GridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("HiddenField1"), HiddenField)
                If hf IsNot Nothing Then
                    id_propuesta = hf.Value
                    index = i
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Array(0) = index
    Array(1) = id_propuesta

    Return Array
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just group radio buttons in a groupbox?? Wouldnt that work better though?
What is this statement meant to do `Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(GridView3.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)` ? Extract data from a datagrid cell and assign it to a checkbox??

You can just use `radD.Text = dgData.Rows(tracker1).DataBoundItem("OptionD").ToString`
where tracker1 is column index and "OptionD" is column name and radA.text is the text in the radio button. and dgData is the name of the datagrid view